# Do Russell's socks form a Dedekind-finite infinite set?

Tags: set-theory

A countable collection of pairwise disjoint two-element sets $(A_n)_{n<\omega}$ is called Russell-sequence if $\prod_{n<\omega} A_n$ is empty. (That is, there is no way to choose one of two socks from $A_n$ simultaneously.) The cardinality of $\bigcup_{n<\omega} A_n$ is called Russell cardinal. Russell cardinal does not exist under the axiom of choice, but its existence is known to be consistent with ZF.

It is known that Russell cardinals are Dedekind-finite. I've tried to prove this, but attempts I have made get stuck. Here is an one of my attempt:

> Assume that there is a one-to-one function $f$ from $\omega$ to $A$. For each $n$, $A_n$ can be included in the image of $f$, or just intersects, or both not. Let $B\subseteq\omega$ be a set of all $n$ such that $A_n$ contains for some $f(k)$, then $\prod_{n\in B} A_n$ is not empty.

I don't know, however, how to proceed above argument. The fact that $\prod_{n\in B}A_n$ is nonempty does not seem to imply $\prod_{n<\omega} A_n$ is nonempty, so we can not reach the contradiction.

Is there any good idea how to resolve the problem I pointed out? or is there any other way to prove this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a slightly wrong definition there. Here's a nice theorem.

> Suppose that $\{A_n\mid n\in\omega\}$ is a family of finite sets, each of size $\geq2$. Then $\bigcup A_n$ is Dedekind-finite if and only if there is no infinite $I\subseteq\omega$ for which $\prod_{i\in I}A_i\neq\varnothing$.

Now Russell socks satisfy the second condition of the theorem. Namely, there is *no* infinite family from which we can choose. And then you can easily show that it is in fact Dedekind-finite.

If all you require is that the entire product is empty you can easily contradict that. Simply pick some family of pairs without a choice function $A_n$ and define $B_{2n}=A_n$ and $B_{2n+1}=\{n\}\times\{0,1\}$. Now $\prod B_n=\varnothing$, but you can easily find an injection from $\omega$ into $\bigcup B_n$.